# C++ : cin while cout

Tags: c++

Well, I'm writing a Chat in C++ to be used in linux terminal. I want to receive messages even while I'm typing. basically, a non-blocking `cin`. I managed to get this work by creating a thread. BUT the problem is that incoming messages and my typing are getting merged together.

Is there any way to separate `cin` line from other lines coming from `cout`?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: a) Don´t use (unsynchronized) threads. b) How about a input "line" while the rest of the console is the output part? For setting cursor positions etc., NCurses will help.

Comment: You might want to take a look at something like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses

Comment: Short answer: `cin` and `cout` are unsuitable for interactive input, they are for reading from/writing to *streams*, not from the user. Hence the recommendation to use something like ncurses, which is a library for interactive user input.

Comment: Since it's a homework, I'm limited by using basic classes.

Comment: @KiraSan Only using the platform-independent classes required by the C++ standard, this is impossible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any way to separate `cin` line from other lines coming from `cout`?

Yes, but it is a little tricky: you need to disable echo for the console, and print the characters typed in by end-user as he types.

When you detect an incoming message, you need to do these three things:

- Clear out all characters on the line the end-user has entered so far
- Print the incoming message
- Print the characters entered so far on the next line.

The end result would look like this:

```
Friend: How are you?                        <== This is your friend's prior message
You: > I am fi                              <== This is the text you've entered so far
```

When the next message comes in before you finished typing, you re-arrange the last lines as follows:

```
Friend: How are you?                        <== This is your friend's prior message
Friend: Are you coming to school tomorrow?  <== This is the new line that came in as the user was typing
You: > I am fi                              <== This is the text you've entered so far, re-printed again
```

Comment: So far, this is the best answer, It helped me understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

My idea is to store incomplete client's message (that has not been sent yet) in a variable and when program receives incoming messages, it should erase client's message with backspaces, write incoming message to cout and then rewrite client's incomplete message.

I have not checked it though.