# How should I use async_read_until and async_write simultaneously in the client app in boost::asio?

Tags: c++, client-server, chat, boost-asio

### My motivation.

I am trying to build a simple messenger. Currently I have written client and server apps that support "mail like functional", that is they lack chat interaction that you have in every instant messenger.

### Here is a model I use.

**Server:** The server for every connected client has a dedicated `Service` class that provides actual service. An instance of the `Service` class has an id.

**Client**: At particular moment simultaneously starts reading messages from and writing messages to the associated `Service` instance.

**Tracker**: Records current sessions of users by saving their logins and `Service` ids in a map. Also records opened chats by saving key-value pairs (chat participant id 1, chat participant id 2). I use logins and ids of users interchangeably because I have a database.

### Here is a typical usage scenario.

1. A user is trying to log in. The server dedicates to the user the `Service` instance with id 1. Then the user identified as Bob.
2. Bob opens a chat with Ann. `Tracker` records that Bob uses `Service` 1 and that Bob opened the chat with Ann.
3. A user is trying to log in. The server dedicates to the user the `Service` instance with id 2. Then the user identified as Ann.
4. Ann opens a chat with Bob. `Tracker` records that Ann uses `Service` 2 and that Ann opened the chat with Bob.
5. Ann writes a message to Bob. `Service` 2 receives the message and asks `Service` 1 to send the message to Bob's chat if Bob has opened the chat with Ann. For that purpose I use `Tracker`. In our case Bob is in the chat so Bob's client app should read the message from `Service` 1. Otherwise `Service` 2 only stores the new message in the database.

When a user opens a chat with somebody the client app simultaneously starts reading and writing messages to the associate `Service` instance.

### Issue

1. Bob opens a chat with Ann. Ann opens a chat with Bob.
2. Ann sends messages. They are displayed in Bobs chat.
3. Bob sends a message. It is not displayed in Ann's chat. Moreover, further Ann's messages are no longer displayed in Bob's chat.

Here is a portion of my server code. I have added some context but you probably want to look at `Service::onMessageReceived`, `Service::receive_message`, `Service::send_to_chat`

```
/// Struct to track active sessions of clients
struct Tracker {
  static std::mutex current_sessions_guard; ///< mutex to lock the map of current sessions between threads
  static std::map<long, long> current_sessions; 
  static std::map<long, int> client_to_service_id;
};
```

Class that provides the actual service in the client-service model

```
class Service {
public:
  void send_to_chat(const std::string& new_message) {
    asio::async_write(*m_sock.get(), asio::buffer(new_message),
      [this]() {
        onAnotherPartyMessageSent(); 
      });
  } 

private:
  void onReceivedReady();
  void receive_message() {
    /// Server loop for reading messages from the client
    spdlog::info("[{}] in receive_message", service_id);

    asio::async_read_until(*m_sock.get(), *(m_message.get()), '\n',
      [this]() {
        onMessageReceived();
      });
  } 
  void onMessageReceived();

private:
  std::shared_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::socket> m_sock; ///< Pointer to an active socket that is used to communicate
                                                 ///< with the client
  int service_id;  
  long dialog_id = -1, client_id = -1, another_party_id = -1;
  std::shared_ptr<asio::streambuf> m_message;
};
```

Definitions of methods

```
void Service::onMessageReceived() {
  /// Updates the database with the new message and asks Service instance of another participant
  /// to send the message if they opened this chat.

  std::istream istrm(m_message.get());
  std::string new_message;
  std::getline(istrm, new_message);
  m_message.reset(new asio::streambuf);

  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> tracker_lock(Tracker::current_sessions_guard);

  if (Tracker::current_sessions.find(another_party_id) != Tracker::current_sessions.end()) {
    if (Tracker::current_sessions[another_party_id] == client_id) {
      int another_party_service_id = Tracker::client_to_service_id[another_party_id];
      std::string formatted_msg = _form_message_str(login, new_message);
      
      spdlog::info("[{}] sends to chat '{}'", another_party_service_id, new_message);

      Server::launched_services[another_party_service_id]->send_to_chat(formatted_msg);
    }
  }
  tracker_lock.unlock();
  receive_message();
}
```

Here is a portion of my client code. I have added some context but you probably want to look at `AsyncTCPClient::onSentReady`, `AsyncTCPClient::message_send_loop`, `AsyncTCPClient::message_wait_loop`.

```
/// Struct that stores a session with the given server
struct Session {
  asio::ip::tcp::socket m_sock; //!< The socket for the client application to connect to the server
  asio::ip::tcp::endpoint m_ep; //!< The server's endpoint
  std::string current_chat;

  std::shared_ptr<asio::streambuf> m_chat_buf;
  std::shared_ptr<asio::streambuf> m_received_message;
};

/// Class that implements an asynchronous TCP client to interact with Service class
class AsyncTCPClient: public asio::noncopyable {

  void onSentReady(std::shared_ptr<Session> session) {
  
    msg_wait_thread.reset(new std::thread([this, session] {
      asio::async_read_until(session->m_sock, *(session->m_received_message.get()), "\n", 
        [this, session] () {
          message_wait_loop(session);
        });
      }));
    msg_wait_thread->detach();

    msg_thread.reset(new std::thread([this, session] {
      message_send_loop(session);
      }));

    msg_thread->detach();
  } 


  void message_send_loop(std::shared_ptr<Session> session) {
    /// Starts loop in the current chat enabling the client to keep sending messages to another party
    logger->info("'{}' in message_send_loop", session->login);

    clear_console();
    m_console.write(session->current_chat);
    m_console.write("Write your message: ");

    std::string new_message;

    // We use a do/while loop to prevent empty messages either because of the client input
    // or \n's that were not read before

    do {
      new_message = m_console.read();
    } while (new_message.empty());
    

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock_std_out(std_out_guard);
    session->current_chat.append(_form_message_str(session->login, new_message));
    lock_std_out.unlock();

    asio::async_write(session->m_sock, asio::buffer(new_message + "\n"), 
      [this, session] () {
        message_send_loop(session);
      }); 
  } 

  void message_wait_loop(std::shared_ptr<Session> session) {
    /// Starts loop in the current chat enabling the client to keep reading messages from another party

    logger->info("'{}' in message_wait_loop", session->login);

    std::istream istrm(session->m_received_message.get());
    std::string received_message;
    std::getline(istrm, received_message);

    session->m_received_message.reset(new asio::streambuf);

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock_std_out(std_out_wait_guard);
    session->current_chat.append(received_message + "\n");
    lock_std_out.unlock();

    clear_console();
    m_console.write(session->current_chat);
    m_console.write("Write your message: ");
    
    asio::async_read_until(session->m_sock, *(session->m_received_message.get()), "\n", 
      [this, session] (std::size_t) {
        message_wait_loop(session);
      });
  }

private:
  asio::io_context m_ios;
};
```

So, when I described the issue I do not have `"'{}' in message_wait_loop"` logs for both clients at the point 3). But I have these logs at the point 2) for the Bob's client.

Also I use Console from [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55414228/simultaneous-input-and-output-in-a-console). It removes echo and controls standard input/output resources by means of mutexes. However it does not solve my problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's too much code and too little. Too much for the question, and too little to actually suggest improvements. I see an overuse of shared_ptr, threads, In particular it is very weird to run async-operations on their own threads. Let alone detached:

```
msg_wait_thread.reset(new std::thread([this, session] {
      asio::async_read_until(session->m_sock, *(session->m_received_message.get()), "\n", 
        [this, session] () {
          message_wait_loop(session);
        });
      }));
    msg_wait_thread->detach();
```

That whole thing is best replaced by the completely equivalent (but safer)

```
  asio::async_read_until(session->m_sock, *(session->m_received_message.get()), "\n", 
    [this, session] () {
      message_wait_loop(session);
    });
```

I imagine the read loop is on a thread so that the input wouldn't block. However, it becomes much easier if you consider the main thread the "UI thread" (it is), and accept that console IO is blocking there, instead posting the resulting requests to a single IO thread for all the non-blocking operations.

If you share a link to a repo or something I'm happy to look at it more.

## UPDATE

In the comments I reviewed the code from the github repo and posted a PR: https://github.com/cepessh/mymsg/pull/1

> This is a very raw proof-of-concept. I have included many changes that
> aren't actually related to the suggested concurrency fix, but they
> happened:
>
> - to allow me to run
> - during review (you will probably want to look at a number of those changes and keep them anyways)
> - fixes that were apparently missing from `main` branch (e.g. the default value for `Message.read_by_recipient` database column)
>
> You should be able to work out what changes were made and why by the
> [commit messages](https://github.com/cepessh/mymsg/pull/1/commits).
>
> Only the last two commits actually focus on the idea discussed [in
> chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228075/discuss-https-stackoverflow-com-a-65970286-85371).
>
> [image]

Comment: I have tried for hours to cut code so that it is not considered as spam. Here's my repo https://github.com/cepessh/mymsg. If you want to build it then you will need to adjust boost path in CMakeLists.txt (also boost::system needs to be build separately in case you do not have it, other boost files are used as header only libraries in my project). If you want to completely replicate the situation then you will need to run sql script in msgDB to create a database and add user. Then adjust the credentials in cfg_server.json

Comment: Okay, so I had exactly the right hunch: https://i.imgur.com/KmrqZNt.png the input action is blocking the IO service.

Comment: I still do not understand how to solve this. If input action is blocking the IO service why does it block only at the 3) point of the issue? So, as far as I understand in my situation the blocking of IO occurs only when the other party actually types something. Moreover, how the blocking of IO also interferes with async_read_until in message_wait_loop? I mean that the handler of async_read_until is not called at the point 3) despite the fact that service send the message. Please, can you elaborate how I should manage the threads?

Comment: It is alwats blocking, but sometimes the timing might be fortunate. E.g. it always doesn't work for me when sending another message both ways (so it's just the first time that sometimes "works")

Comment: "How does it interfere"? Really, you should ask: how not. You run the io_service on a thread. Meaning the thread can execute ONE handler at a time. Some of your handlers do blocking `std::cin` IO, meaning they prevent any other completion handlers (e.g. from the async_read_until) from executing until that completes.

Comment: "How do I solve this" - I would do as I said in my answer: _"However, it becomes much easier if you consider the main thread the "UI thread" (it is), and accept that console IO is blocking there, instead posting the resulting requests to a single IO thread for all the non-blocking operations."_

Comment: Let's see if we can move this to a chat and I can try things out

Comment: So, I can create a chat manually. I tried to invite you here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228075/discuss-https-stackoverflow-com-a-65970286-85371 (I think you might still need 20 rep before you can /join/ but at least you should be able to read, which gives me more space/formatting options)

Comment: updated answer with [PR](https://github.com/cepessh/mymsg/pull/1) for proof of concept fix

Comment: I've done some more reviewing and found some issues (mostly around output buffers being local or temporaries, besides some threading concerns, also shutdown cleanliness. The stuff is here if you want to see them: https://github.com/sehe/mymsg/tree/sehe